# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of laplacian matrix of cycle graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I'm interested in finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Laplacian matrix of a cycle graph with $n$ vertices (so - a 2-regular connected graph with $n$ vertices). The degree matrix is $D=2I$, and the adjacency matrix is (if I'm not mistaken):
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & ... &0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 \\ . & . & . & . & . & .  \\ . & . & . & . & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & . & . &  1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
So overall the Laplacian matrix is:
$$L=D-A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & ... &0 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 2& -1 & ... & 0 \\ . & . & . & . & . & .  \\ . & . & . & . & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & . & . &  -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

Since the sum of each row is $0$, I can already see that $0$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $(1,1,...)$. I think it's also pretty clear that $0$ is a simple eigenvalue from the shape of the matrix.
Does anyone have an idea on how to find the remaining eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Can this even be done for general $n$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $L$ is a circulant matrix.

Therefore, the vector

$$(\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_{n-1})$$ of its eigenvalues is obtained by taking the Discrete Fourier Transform of the generating sequence (first line of matrix $L$).

$$(c_0,c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_{n-1})=(2, -1, 0, \cdots, 0, -1)$$

i.e.:

$$\lambda_k=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c_j e^{\tfrac{2i\pi jk}{n}}, \ \ \ (k=0,1,2, \cdots n-1)$$

which in fact can be given a real expression:

$$\lambda_k=2-2 \cos(2 \pi k)/n)=4 \sin^2 (\pi k/n) \ \ k=0,1,\cdots (n-1)$$

Nothing surprizing, matrix $L$ is symmetric with real entries. See p.7 of [this reference](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/%7Emohar/Papers/Montreal.pdf).

The associated eigenvectors are the columns of $F_n$, the  Discrete Fourier matrix of order $n$, i.e.,

$$V_k=\begin{pmatrix}e^{\tfrac{2i\pi 0k}{n}}\\e^{\tfrac{2i\pi 1k}{n}}\\ \vdots \\ e^{\tfrac{2i\pi (n-1)k}{n}}\end{pmatrix}$$

See [this document](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Spring17/Circulant-Matrices.pdf) where the initial example is precisely matrix $L$...

Comment: Thank you. In our specific case, the circulant matrix is symmetric, so the eigenvectors can be chosen to be with real entries. Do you have an idea on how to find these real eigenvectors, using the given form of the eigenvectors via the DFT?

Comment: The real (this time exact...) version of eigenvalues is : $\lambda_k=2-2 \cos(2 \pi k)/n)=4 \sin^2 (\pi k/n)$, $ \ k=0,1, \cdots (n-1)$. I erase the previous answers in order not to confuse future readers. I now look at what can be said about eigenvectors.

Comment: Are the imaginary part of the $V_k$s themselves eigenvectors ?

Comment: Yes, I think they are. I know that the conjugate of an eigenvector (vector with conjugate entries) is the eigenvector of the conjugate eigenvalue. But the eigenvalues are real, so its an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue. So if I take the linear combination $-i(v-v^*)$ I get an eigenvector which is the imaginary part of $v$. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Pleasure! Thanks for the proof!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, it is a circulant matrix with almost all entries $0$. But the values aren't particularly easy on the eyes.